# Unchecking Boxes -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to uncheck all boxes at once?

I have a 4x4 table of checkboxes and I set all their ID's to "cb". I want to have a button that clears all of them, so I tried doing something like below:

```
document.getElementById("cb").checked="false"
```

But on the screen, they still remain checked. Is this possible?

Comment: IDs, by definition, must be unique!

Comment: 'I set all their ID's to "cb"' --- Wrong!!! do you know what the word "identifier" means?

Comment: You should not have two elements on the same page with identical "id" attributes.

Comment: Why the quotes in `"false"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID's are unique, so having multiple elements with the same ID wont solve the problem, it will only make your markup invalid. Use classes instead:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");

for (i=0; boxes.length<i; i++) {
    boxes[i].checked = false;
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas as a property, `checked` should be a boolean

Comment: Any chance `boxes.length` is a getter and should be cached? Not that it matters with 16 elements though.

Comment: I did a little copy/paste and the false was quoted for a few seconds before I was able to change it, so I guess that is what the comment about boolean was about. @JanDvorak - caching the length is sometimes a good idea, but for this it just seems unnecessary ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article [Javascript Check and Uncheck All Checkboxes](http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/javascript/checkboxes.asp)

Here is the code below:

Script

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function checkAll(field)
    {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
        field[i].checked = true ;
    }

    function uncheckAll(field)
    {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
        field[i].checked = false ;
    }

</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="myform" action="checkboxes.asp" method="post">
<b>Your Favorite Scripts & Languages</b><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="1">Java<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="2">Javascript<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="3">Active Server Pages<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="4">HTML<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="5">SQL<br>

<input type="button" name="CheckAll" value="Check All"
onClick="checkAll(document.myform.list)">
<input type="button" name="UnCheckAll" value="Uncheck All"
onClick="uncheckAll(document.myform.list)">
<br>
</form>
```

Best Regards

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts here? We don't like link-only answers here - they look like spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
function toggle(state) {
    var cb = document.getElementsByName('cb');
    for (var i = cb.length; i--;) {
        cb[i].checked = typeof state != 'undefined' ? state : !cb[i].checked;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
toggle(false); // Uncheck all
toggle(true);  // Check all
toggle();      // Toggle all
```

In this example you select checkboxes by the name attribute. You can also use class name and select inputs with [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) methods.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kCmqL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script language="javascript">
function checkUnCheckAll(formname)
{
  var checkboxes = new Array(); 
  checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
      checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### [`More`](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/checkuncheck-all-checkboxes)

Comment: Your source should be directly within the answer, not as a comment.

Comment: 1) Function name does not correspond with its effect. 2) I think it is better to name an array as 'inputs', not 'checkboxes'. 3) It is not necessary to define checkboxes as `new Array`... `var checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');` is enough for this variant

Answer (score 0):

You can also your same Name to all controls as below:

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="compare" id="compare" value="1" />
    <input type="Checkbox" name="compare" id="Checkbox1" value="5" />
    <input type="Checkbox" name="compare" id="Checkbox2" value="8" />
    <input type="Checkbox" name="compare" id="Checkbox3" value="10" />

<input type="button" value="select all" onclick="javascript:checkAll()"/>
<input type="button" value="unckeck all" onclick="javascript: unCheckAll()"/> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll()
    {
        var c = document.getElementsByName("compare");
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            c[i].checked = true;
        }

    }
    function unCheckAll() {
        var c = document.getElementsByName("compare");
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            c[i].checked = false;
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you already have an answer, I thought I'd post the following as an option also. Given the following minimal/demonstrative HTML mark-up:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="something" name="cb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="something" name="cb" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="something" name="cb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="something" name="cb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="something" name="cb" checked />
<input type="checkbox" class="something" name="cb" checked />
```

The following JavaScript can be used to check, uncheck or toggle all `checkboxes` returned by the selector:

```
Object.prototype.check = function (newState) {
    switch (newState.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'toggle':
            for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i<len; i++){
                this[i].checked = !this[i].checked;
            }
            break;
        case 'check':
            for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
                this[i].checked = true;
            }
            break;
        case 'uncheck':
            for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
                this[i].checked = false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return this;
};
```

To toggle all, call with (for example):

[`document.getElementsByClassName('something').check('toggle');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sJZLu/).

To check all, call with (for example):

[`document.getElementsByClassName('something').check('check');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sJZLu/1/).

To uncheck all, call with (for example):

[`document.getElementsByClassName('something').check('uncheck');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sJZLu/2/).